# Watchdog test in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, watchdog

I want to test the watchdog in my system.
How can I totally freeze the Windows XP, in order to let the watchdog to perform reset?

I tried the "fork bomb", but it didn't help.

I don't care if OS will be damaged or destroyed. This is test station, so I can restore it quickly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new process which just wastes CPU cycles, something like:

```
int main()
{
    for(;;)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

and give it realtime priority from the task manager. The system will hang.

[More on realtime priority](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100610-00/?p=13753).

Comment: Of course, if your test machine's processor has more than one core, you'll need to have a corresponding number of threads stuck in an infinite loop.